# How to find out who added a user or modified IAM roles of a specific user in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I tried but could not figure out that how to find out who added a user or modified IAM roles of a specific user in GCP.

is anyone aware of any method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this information through **Logs Viewer** please check the following URL for [Logs Viewer query interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#the_user_interfaces) where you can find more information

And for this specific event you can use the following query to search it in your project:

1. Go to [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?_ga=2.153367928.1971724225.1600087887-638966553.1591892739)
2. Select a Google Cloud project.
3. Use the advanced query interface:
   [image]
4. Paste the following query:

```
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission="resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy"
protoPayload.response.bindings.members="user:emailuser@gmail.com"
```

Change the emailuser@gmail.com for the user you are looking for.

5. Click on the start button.

[image]

And you will see something like:

[image]

On View Options you can click on Expand All for more information:

[image]

Also you can see those events on the Activity tab

[image]

I hope this information would be useful to you

Comment: Thank you for putting your effort and placing the required information in such a simple format.

Comment: @d.s I'm happy to help, if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Comment: I tired to vote but got the below message:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.